# AWK, fatal: attempt to access field -1

Tags: bash, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to make awk correctly printing the structure of the input file when I'm trying to use `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; NF > 1 {print $(NF-1)}'`.

**Expected output**

```
bogota
bogota
bogota
bogota
bogota



whitehouse stn
```

With the proposed attempt, I obtain:

```
bogota
bogota
bogota
bogota
bogota
whitehouse stn
```

And, if I don't use `NF > 1`, I get the error mentioned on this post title.

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: And what output do you expect, exactly? If the line is blank, `NF` will be 0, not 1, which is why you get the error.

Comment: What would you want output if a line contained just 1 field?

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton and good point of view. In that case, I'd rather prefer an empty line.

Comment: @Alejandro OK, I just posted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, you want:

```
awk -F, '{print $(NF?NF-1:0)}'
```

That will print the second last field if there are two or more fields, and otherwise the entire line.

Explanation:

The expression inside the parentheses is the standard `?:` ternary operator, which has the form `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`. In awk, a numeric value (like `NF`) is true if it is not 0.

It also important to know that in awk, the `$` is a unary operator taking a numeric argument. `$(i)` is the `ith` field if `0 < i ≤ NF`; the entire line if `i == 0`; and an empty string if `i > NF`. Other values of `i` are illegal.

Comment: Yes! Thank so much, That is what I wanted. Would be too much if I ask you how `$(NF?NF-1:0)` works?

Comment: @Alejandro Its a [ternary op](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp). You may also choose to write it as `awk -F, 'NF{print $(NF-1)}' file`

Comment: @jaypal: I moved the explanation to the answer. And your program is not equivalent, since it prints nothing if `NF` is 0, and the expected output is a blank line (which happens to be the value of `$0` in that case :) )

Comment: @rici Aah my bad. I didn't read the question properly. To print the blank lines, `awk -F, 'NF{print $(NF-1);next}1' file` might be more appropriate but yours is more idiomatic. `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{print $(NF>1?NF-1:"")}' file
```

Comment: Good day Ed Morton, sorry to ask you through this way. But, is this: `$(NR%2=1?sum:"0")` correct?

Comment: @Alejandro that depends what you want it to do. Maybe you should post a new question with it's own sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130722/awk-arithemetical-op-on-odd-line

Comment: Then no, Kents answer to that question was exactly correct and the script you posted doesn't make any sense wrt the posted desired output.