# AWK, Arithemetical OP on odd line

Tags: bash, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to do an arithmetical op with awk, only on odd lines.

So far I have done:

```
SUM=100 ; awk -v var1=$SUM '{sum = $1 + var1 ;print $(NR%2=1?sum:"0")}' file
```

**INPUT**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**Expected output**

```
101
2
103
4
```

Thank in advance for any clue or suggestion.

Comment: You should post a new question rather than update the answered question with additional queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want this?

```
awk -v var1="$SUM" 'NR%2{$0+=var1}7' file
```

it outputs:

```
101
2
103
4
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be too much if I ask you how `NR%2{$0=$0+var1}7` works?

Comment: @Alejandro if odd line number, do plus on input line, otherwise leave the input line as it is, finally print line.

Comment: @Alejandro: The key is that `NR` is the current line count. `NR%2` will be non-zero (true) if `NR` is odd.

Comment: Thank @JimMischel. I did't make myself clear, what I want to do is: to do an arith op with odd lines and another arith op with even ones, and both arith ops printed in the same output.